# Resolution of forces (vector components) to find the resultant force

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, coordinate-systems, statics

*I'm a CAIE AS-Level student and I'm having a bit of problem with a physics question.
It goes like this,*

**An object X rests on a smooth horizontal surface. Two horizontal forces act on X as shown in Figure 1.1,**

[image: Figure 1.1]

A force of 55 N is applied to the right. A force of 18 N is applied at an angle of 115 degrees to the direction of the 55 N force.

1. **Use the resolution of forces to show that the magnitude of the resultant force acting on X is 65 N.**

---

I know from the marking scheme that the vector components would be,

- Horizontal: 55 + 18 Cos 65
- Vertical: 18 Sin 65

I was taught that the component of the vector along the horizontal plane of the angle is always F Cos θ, and the vertical component is F Sin θ.

What I would like to know is, how would you annotate the diagram or draw a rough one, in order to come up with these components? Also, how would you use these components to prove the statement of question - the resultant force is 65N?.

I will really appreciate if anyone would be kind enough to take out the time and explain the correct procedure that should be followed in this question and others similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

"I was taught that the component of the vector along the horizontal plane of the angle is always F Cos θ, and the vertical component is F Sin θ."

This statement could cause confusion. Here is a safer and more general statement:

When a vector is resolved into components at right angles to each other, for a component that is at angle $\theta$ to the vector,
$$\text{magnitude of component} = (\text{magnitude of the vector}) \times \cos \theta.$$
I Recommend you apply this rule to your forces. Remember that $\cos 25° = \sin 65°$. I suspect that you had not known how to interpret the angle $\theta$.

Note that the components don't *have* to be horizontal and vertical. For example, you will certainly come across objects on slopes, and it is often useful to resolve into directions parallel to, and normal to, the slope.

Going back to your question, once you have found the vertical component and the sum of the two horizontal components, you can use a right angled vector addition triangle to find the magnitude and direction of the resultant force.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible (and arguably simpler) to solve this problem *without* resolving the forces into perpendicular components. Thinking about adding the given forces using the parallelogram law, you can see that you want the length of the third side of a triangle with sides $18$ and $55$ and an angle of $115^o$ between them. You can use the [cosine rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) to find this.

Comment: It is indeed simpler to solve it by using the cosine rule, but the question explicitly asks to solve it by the resolution of vectors. Anyway, I figured out why 55N vector was added in the horizontal component.

Thank you.